# cli window on ubuntu under oracle vm

Tags: command-line, oracle, text

My Ubuntu boots up to GUI interface.
How do I get to the cli or at least a text window? I can't do anything useful with a gui.

Comment: If you do not need a GUI then why did you install one in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Access command line with Ctrl+Alt+T or Ctrl+Alt+F1

You can also set up Ubuntu to boot to the command line instead of GUI.

From a terminal edit /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Save the file, then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Next time you boot it will stay in text (command line) mode instead of starting the GUI. If you want to start the GUI from the command line, use the command "startx".

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Alt-F1, or click the Unity icon and type "terminal"